# If server doesn't have mod rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a question regarding mod_rewrite. I know in htaccess I can do the `<IfModule>`, but what about in PHP? In html I am writing out my links like `projects/24` which really is `action=projects&id=24`. If the server someone installs this app on doesn't have mod_rewrite, how in PHP do I change the links to just GET vars?

Comment: wouldn't adding mod_rewite be the easiest solution?

Comment: Sure adding mod_rewrite would be easier, but if this is an app I want to sell, I want it to be painless for the user to install. This is just a fall back. Sure, they can install mod_rewrite, but if its not installed, I don't want my app to be broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [apache_get_modules()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-modules.php)

**Edit:**
I'm not sure which handicap voted down the correct answer, but he apparently can't rtm.

Here is some code to illustrate:

```
<?php

if (in_array("mod_rewrite", apache_get_modules())) {
   echo 'has rewrite';
} else {
   echo 'no rewrite';
}

?>
```

Use this to decide which kind of link you want to write.

Comment: No problem. Also, remember to check if the function apache_get_modules exists, they may be running IIS or something else.

Comment: yeah I figured that part out. I was testing on localhost and what you had worked fine. Pushed it to my server and got an error saying that function didnt exist so I added `function_exists()` to the mix and all was good

Answer (score 0):

> how in PHP do I change the links to just GET vars?

Just make your all your links using variables.
And choose their appearance based on the some configuration setting, like Wordpress does.

Comment: You mean rewriting the HTML output? Or you mean generating links using a function / macro and doing a rewrite in there?

Comment: yeah basically the links will read differently based on whether the server has mod_rewrite or not so the HTML output will be different

Answer (score 0):

There are workarounds using ErrorDocument and handling the failed requests in userland (= php script). But this will (1) pollute the log, and (2) does not work with POST requests (depending on server). Wouldn't bother with that.

A practical alternative is utilizing `PATH_INFO` for clean urls in combination with one or multiple root scripts. You will need to use it with e.g. `+MultiViews` or `SetHandler` or [`DefaultType`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#defaulttype) and `ForceType` (which can be used to plant a php script sans extension). <sup>[1]</sup>
But oftentimes those are disallowed directives too, if not even mod_rewrite is enabled.

<sub>[1] Don't forget a FilesMatch section to limit the effect, or disable it in subdirectories again.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're going to end up with, but this might push you in the right direction:

http://www.tutorio.com/tutorial/php-alternative-to-mod-rewrite-for-se-friendly-urls

There are of course other problems with this, the biggest being problems caching and indexing these sorts of URLs in search engines.